# Entity framework code first, get access to foreign key value

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Say we have a project with this entities:

```
class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    ...
}

class Message
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Now consider a scenerio where i want to get all the messages that a certain user posted, how can one achieve this without pulling the user information aswell? (without using the context.Users.Include(...) ) ?
I know that the entity framework creates a column in the Message table that holds the Id of the user that posted this message, but how can i have an access to this value? as it is not a property in my original class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a navigation property into the `Message` class:

```
public class Message
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And then query your context like this:

```
var userMessages = context.Messages
    .Where(m => m.User.Id == 5);
```

This is the tidier way of doing it. Alternatively, you could start with the user, but this is a little more awkward:

```
var userMessages = context.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == 5)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Messages);
```

Both methods will ultimately produce the similar SQL, something like this:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Column1],
       [Extent1].[Column2],
       [Extent1].[Column3]
FROM [dbo].[Messages] AS [Extent1] 
WHERE 5 = [Extent1].[UserId]
```

Comment: Hey DavidG! what is the difference between using the ForeignKey annotation against not using it?

Comment: There really isn't a difference, if you want to be explicit, then feel free to add it in. You actually don't need the attribute as Entity Framework will, by convention, map `User` navigation property to an Id field called `UserId`.

Comment: Does this creates any connection between the two entities? will deleting one of them will cause the deletion of the other?

Comment: You already have the connection between them, EF convention will create the foreign key.

Comment: A foreign key constraint won't actually be created until you declare WillCascadeOnDelete. The FK annotation will be solely for EF to tell which join attribute to use (and create an index on the column if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Oh i see, so incase that i want to be able to query like the example, it this best practice to define the foreign key like this? or i better define that property as a normal property and not foreign key, so the database won't need to do joins with other tables?

Comment: If you do it this way, the user objects will be read during the query in order to access their ID property.

Comment: @Yushatak No, that is absolutely **not** correct. Entity Framework uses expressions to create the query. In this case you would get a query like `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Messages] AS [Extent1] WHERE 5 = [Extent1].[UserId]`

Answer (score 2):

You can explictly define the FK so that you don't have to resolve the User object.

```
class Message
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Then you operate on the User when you need to, but if you just want to pull by UserID or change the UserID you can do so.

Comment: Hey Yushatak! what is the difference between using the ForeignKey annotation against not using it (but leaving the virtual on like DavidG posted)?

Comment: If you use the annotation you create an *accessible* key property (in this case UserID) which you can read/write/manipulate. If you do not use the annotation this happens behind-the-scenes and is not made available to you through EF to manipulate.

Comment: Apparently the manual FK is not necessary as the expression resolves to using the ID property anyway in EF (per DavidG).